# How get text from combobox or dropdown in Excel Addin?

Tags: c#, excel, combobox

I have ribbon, group, button and combobox. Combobox filled collection of values.
But if I choose value and click button I get empty string.

```
    private void ribbon_Button1Clicked()
    {
        var ribbon = new SampleRibbon();
        MessageBox.Show(ribbon.comboBox1.Text);
    }
```

What wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are instantiating a new instance of SampleRibbon. Try the below.

```
private void ribbon_Button1Clicked(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(comboBox1.text);
}
```

You may want to properly format your event handler for the button click as well.